# New screen flickering when charged

Tags: samsung, charging, screen, touchscreen, broken-screen

i had my screen broken unfortunately. I received a replacement that i don't  know if it is an official one, that was excellent until i put it to charge. The screen lightly flickers.  I don't have an official charger and mine outputs 5v and 0.18A. when the phone is down the screen is ok. It flickers when i touch the metal to the side of the battery.

This happens even when minimal pressure which suggests a grounding issue? When non conductive materials touch the side - even if with a lot of pressure nothing happens. And finally, this happens only when charging. My phone is Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016).

EDIT 1: I can confirm it is a grounding issue because when i touch the metal surface with a metal connected to a GND, the flickering stops completely

EDIT 2: I went to the repair shop and got an official Samsung charger (5v, 1.55A). The flickering has almost vanished. You have to pay real close attention to see a very slight flickering when it charges and you touch the metal surface around the screen. Still no clue on what is happening.

Comment: Sounds like what you suspect but unless you change the charger and power point you are connected to one can't be sure. But flickering / ghost touches are attributed to grounding

Comment: tomorrow i will check with the official charger. what do you mean "power point"? do you think its solvable? is it a defect screen or a bad reassembly?

Comment: Power point = where you plug in the charger (try a different one since that could also have earth leak issues, unlikely though). I have no experience of changing screens so can't say and in any case such hardware issues are best left to competent people who have the skill and tools. I am only trying to rule out other things before that path of service centre

Comment: yes this happens in all power points with all (unoficial) chargers i have tried so far

Comment: To me it looks like a visit to service centre for a check and solution. Things can't be very different with official charger since you have tried multiple chargers

Comment: yes its just that i just received it back from service after a screen replacement....

Comment: I see no other course. Tough luck

Comment: Ah those Chinese replacement screens...

Comment: @esQmo so you think it is an unoficial screen? if so, the issue is unsolvable right?

Comment: i am hoping its just bad assembky

Comment: What's your question? You've done some good experiments here and it seems like you've already found what's wrong.

Comment: i dont know what is wrong actually. my question is "how do i stop this completely?". it is a groundinf issue. can i open up tge case or something and reconnect it?

Comment: If it's a Chinese replacement screen, you need to get it replaced. Your charger may also be the cause! Does this happen while charging from a computer?

Comment: Yes! It happens with every charger but with the original one it is barely noticable.